# Empty areas in figure and optimal curve fitting

Tags: metapost, curve-fitting, bezier

I need to create a logo (well, a part of it) as an outline. The relevant part in MetaPost looks:

```
beginfig(1)
  path ellipse;
  ellipse = fullcircle xscaled 5in yscaled 1in;
  for k = 0 step 45 until 135:
    fill ellipse rotated k;
  endfor;

  for k = 0 step 45 until 135:
    unfill ellipse scaled 0.8 rotated k;
  endfor;

endfig;
end.
```

With this I got

[image: white filled flower]

because `unfill` is just a fill with white.

I would like to get an eps, pdf, or svg with empty area inside. Like this:

[image: empty filled flower]

Of course, if would be nice if the curves be optimal because otherwise the logo would make some unpleasant surprises while used in texts. The optimal solution is just two path: one  consisting of 16 Bézier curves going anticlockwise followed by another internal path consisting of 16 smaller Bézier curves.

Right now I just exported black and white logo to 6000dpi png and used the program `autotrace` to get the curves. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I think that the only way to do this in Metapost will be to define a path and a pen that gives you the desired outline. Metapost cannot convert the intersection of two filled regions into a path.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no MetaPost wizard, but after a little experimentation I got this result.

```mp
beginfig(1)
  path ellipse, segment, outline, outside, inside;
  pair start, stop;

  ellipse = fullcircle xscaled 5in yscaled 1in;
  stop := ellipse intersectionpoint (ellipse rotated 45);
  start := (ellipse rotated -45) intersectionpoint ellipse;
  segment := (ellipse cutbefore start) -- (ellipse cutafter stop);
  outline := segment for k = 45 step 45 until 315: -- segment rotated k endfor -- cycle;

  outside := outline;
  inside := outline scaled 0.8;

  fill outside -- (reverse inside) -- cycle;
endfig;
```

I modified your code to get the flowery shape into a path variable `outline`. Then I used a trick to only fill in the area *inbetween* the two curves. I don't know a proper reference for it; the Metafun manual (section 1.5) does talk about it, saying

> This feature depends on the POSTSCRIPT way of filling closed paths, which comes down to filling either the left or the right hand side of a curve.

Notice the `reverse`, which serves a critical role: it reverses the orientation of the inner path. If you `draw` instead of `fill` the shape, you'll see some more of what's going on.

As @Aditya alludes to, MetaPost can't really `unfill` areas. But in special cases you can use this approach to get around that limitation.